# ANTLR Comment Propagation

Tags: antlr, antlr4

Is there a method to propagate a comment in ANTLR to the code generated?
e.g. if I have the Subversion revision number keyword ($Rev$) in a comment within the *.g4 file, is there a way for this to be within the generated code, so that I know that the parser was generated with that revisions version of the language?

Cheers,
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, we are not copying the comments from the grammar into the generated code, although we should. Added https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/375

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt reply, and for adding this to the feature request list. As a work around I've added `@members { public final String VERSION = "$Rev$."; }` so that I get the version attached to the parser/lexer classes. I am relatively new to using ANTLR, and have not tried adding any code into the grammar files, does this seem a reasonable solution?